# How to shift date field in mongodb for all records in a collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have a demo site with some static data that keeps aging off and I'd like to run a mongo query to shift the dates by 30 days. Here is an example of the data. Using mongodb 4.4.3

```
{
    "_id" : "62bda37a4d28f5df2e0ab07f",
    "qty" : 1,
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2022-06-30T13:22:02.368Z"),
    "price" : 4230.0,
    "ownership" : "Owned",
    "itemType" : "EXPIRING_SOON",
    "expirationDate" : ISODate("2022-07-21T04:00:00.000Z"),
    "serialNumber" : "20202868089"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "expirationDate": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$subtract": [
            {
              "$toLong": "$expirationDate"
            },
            2592000000
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here, we re-compute the `expirationDate` field, by first subtracting `259200000 milliseconds (30 days)` from the current expiration date, and then we use `$merge`, to update the collection as well. You can use `$add` instead of `$subtract` to increase the expiry date as well. Here is the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rsJ80iGcaJd).

You can also use the `update` function to perform this if you want the whole operation to be atomic. Like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "expirationDate": {
        "$toDate": {
          "$subtract": [
            {
              "$toLong": "$expirationDate"
            },
            2592000000
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

See it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uDDDhDonQ_K).

Comment: Thanks, any reason id be seeing Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms when running the first query? I changed db.collection to be db.item.

Comment: Make sure that the collection name in `$merge` `into` value is also correct.  Try running it without the `$merge` stage once because merge updates the collection. I believe it doesn't returns the updated docs.

Comment: Ah yea its just that it doesnt return anything changes the collection name in both places does make it work even though it says 0

Answer (score 0):

See the `$dateSubtract` aggregation operation. This with a `$merge` will do the trick.

Comment: the `$dateSubtract` operator is present in mongo version 5.0 and above. The author has version 4.4.3.